# How to estimate population mean by bootstrap sampling?

Tags: statistics, sampling, confidence-interval, bootstrap-sampling

Let's say I have a population of size 1M, and I took a sample of 10k. For each individual of the 10k sample, I recorded an observation x. Afterwords I subsampled the 10k sample 1000 times with replacements and calculated each subsample's mean(x). Now I have a distribution of 1000 means from the subsamples. I can calculate mean, standard deviation, etc. from this mean distribution. Now, how should I go about estimating the mean of the entire population with a 95% confidence interval?

Is it just mean of the 1k subsamples ± 1.96* sd(1k subsamples)?

additional info:
I subsampled the 10k sample 1000 times, each time taking 10k elements from the original sample with replacement.

Comment: Do we need to know the size of the subsamples?

Comment: the subsamples are also 10k size. 100% subsampling with replacement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some background on nonparametric bootstrapping.

Suppose you have
a sample $X_1, \dots, X_n$ from a population with unknown (but assumed
existing) mean $\mu.$ If you knew the distribution of $V = \bar X - \mu,$
then you could find lower and upper values $L$ and $U$, respectively,
such that $P(L \le \bar X = \mu \le U) = 0.95,$ and after obvious
algebraic manipulation $P(\bar X - U \le \mu \le \bar X - L) = .95,$
so that a 95% confidence interval for $\mu$ would be 
$(\bar X - U, \bar X - L).$

However, because you do not know the distribution of $V$, you enter the
'bootstrap world' to seek suitable estimates of $L$ and $U.$ Here
we (temporarily) use $\mu^* = \bar X$ as a proxy for the actual population mean $\mu.$
We take a large number $B$ of re-samples of size $n$ with replacement from the sample, and find $\bar X_i^*$ for each. Then
we cut 2.5% from each tail the re-sampled distribution of the 
$V_i^* = \bar X_i^* - \mu^*$ to get estimates $L^*$ and $U^*$ of $L$ and $U,$
respectively.

Returning to the 'real world' we use $(\bar X - U^*, \bar X - L^*)$
as a 95% bootstrap CI for $\mu.$ Notice that here $\bar X$ has returned
to its original role as the sample mean of the original data.

---

*Example (with code):* For simplicity, using smaller samples than in your example, I generate
a sample of size $n = 200$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 50, \sigma = 7)$ to use
as (fake) data. Then I take $B = 10,000$ bootstrap re-samples to get
an approximate 95% CI for $\mu.$

In the R code below, I use `re` instead
of `*` to denote quantities based on re-sampling. I have used a for-loop
instead of more elegant structures available in R, in case you are not familiar
with R. In case you are familiar with R, I have included the seeds I used
for the pseudorandom number generator so you can replicate what I have done.

```
set.seed(1234); n = 200; x = rnorm(n, 50, 7)
a.obs = mean(x);  s.obs = sd(x); pm = c(-1,1)
a.obs + pm*qt(.975, 99)*s.obs/sqrt(n)
## 48.59325 50.59812    # traditional t conf int, assuming normal data
summary(x)
##   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##  30.01   44.58   48.80   49.60   53.87   71.31 

set.seed(1235)
B = 10^4;  v.re = numeric(B)
for(i in 1:B) {
   a.re = mean(sample(x, n, repl=T))
   v.re[i] = a.re - a.obs }
L = quantile(v.re, .025);  U = quantile(v.re, .975)
a.obs - U; a.obs - L
##    97.5% 
## 48.59839 
##     2.5% 
## 50.59273
```

This procedure would protect against bias if the data were from a skewed
distribution. It assumes that the empirical CDF of the data approaches the
population CDF for a sufficiently large $n.$

In some cases, the bootstrap CI can be a little shorter than the traditional t
confidence interval. The t interval assumes normality and so 'contemplates'
the existence of possible values in both directions not occurring in our
sample of size $n.$  By contrast, the bootstrap CI uses only the data which
lie inside $(30.01, 71.31).$

---

*Notes:* (a) The idea behind your suggested procedure assumes normal data.
It offers no protection against bias from skewed data. Also, the standard deviations $S^*$
of the re-samples will estimate the population SD $\sigma$, so you'd need
to use $\bar S^*/\sqrt{n}$ instead.

(b) Your procedure is more like a *parametric* bootstrap. If you have normal data, I do not
see the point of bootstrapping because the traditional t CI would give about
the same results--with greater accuracy and less fuss. In my view, the only
reason to use a parametric bootstrap would be for data known to be from
a distribution other than normal (perhaps Laplace, gamma, or Weibull) where
the procedures for exact CIs are computationally messy or may be subject to debate.

If you want to describe in a Comment any doubts you have about the nature of your data, or
your specific reason for using bootstrap methods, I would try to respond
accordingly.

Comment: Thanks so much! The observation I'm recording in the population is not normally distributed. It very much skews to the right. However, the means of the observations taken from the bootstrap sub-samples are normally distributed.

I was also told that I can use the standard error of the mean of my sample to estimate confidence interval, without the whole bootstrap process. Essentially mean of the sample ± 1.96*standard error. When I tried this method, the result is very close to the bootstrap values. But I don't understand why z-score would still work when the distribution is not normal.

Comment: By the Central Limit Theorem, sample means of non-normal data are nearly normal, especially if the population is symmetrical; for large $n$ if not symmetrical. Roughly speaking $T = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{S/\sqrt{n}}$ is _approximately_ normally distributed if $n$ is moderately large and the population isn't too far from normal.